The Review Edits page width for before-after currently does not scale to table sizes
For example, on this edit review:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/36462696
During review it was impossible to tell where the actual edit was, until I figured out that there might be additional table columns that the page wasn't showing me, and hadn't provided a scrollbar for.
The sidebar (Approve, reject etc) squashed the display size of the before and after areas, and I had to select text in the table and drag right so that it would scroll. Post-review, the sidebar isn't visible and so the problem goes away.
Please Fix.

Took me a while to interpret this one, I thought additional columns had been added to the table and couldn't find any of that. But no the actual issue is that if you squash the page down to a mobile size, indeed eventually some columns will "fluently" disappear from existence. In the future, it pays to be specific about what you're looking at. Display size, browser version, etc.

As Gimby said, some table columns will get cut off if the screen size is too small and horizontal scrolling will be needed to see that content. This is fairly common practice for responsive design of tables. There is a scrollbar that appears at the bottom of the table when this happens, which I understand is much harder to find on longer tables. This use case is pretty rare and responsive design for tables aren't prefect but necessary. I don't see an easy alternative so I'm marking this as [status-bydesign].

@Carrott "and hadn't provided a scrollbar for." doesn't sound like the scroll bar is there?

@Gimby sounds to me like it's the side menu that squishes the page. The menu with the review feedback options. And when that menu is present, you get narrower view without a scrollbar. Here is how a reviewed item looks (without a side menu). Here is how a review with actions looks. Note that the captured area is exactly the same - the content on the page is different. You can see how the second one is much narrower. (I didn't look for a review with scrollable content)

@VLAZ hm right. That is indeed a big difference, but the scrollbars are still there as said. Wrong problem description.

@metamorphosis: if we didn't get the interpretation correct, could you please provide some additional details and screenshots of what you're seeing?

The edit has been reviewed, the problem is only visible when you're reviewing the edit due to the side-pane. I am doing this on a 1080p monitor, not mobile.
VLAZ is correct. The problem is solely with tables, or at least that's the only place I've come across where it's an issue, so far.

I think the review-options-container is not necessary here (neither is the side-by-side view), because it just narrows down the width available for the post's content. I can "reproduce" (because I get scrollbars, like Gimby mentioned) by downsizing the window: Screenshot. Could you please try that, and scroll down to confirm whether you do get scrollbars or not? If you don't, share a screenshot of it (just that part), and the OS/browser info and so on. Test it without extensions/scripts. I'm on Windows 10 using Waterfox.

As mentioned, the problem was only visible during edit review. It is NOT VISIBLE post-review. NO SCROLLBAR is visible during review.
Firefox most recent version, no extensions, Windows 10.  Cheers.
If it is possible to undo an edit review and mark it as reviewable again, you may see it for yourself.
